# Why date is getting a wrong value?

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare two dates using getTime() method but first date is always inferior to the second. After debugging, I figured that the first date (endTime) is taking 31-12-1969 07:00:00 instead of 01-01-1970 07:00:00. This is the code snippet:

```
if (endTime.before(currentTime)) {
             // action
    }
```

Note: I tried it on a different Timezone (UTC) and it worked perfectly the endTime = 01-01-1970 07:00:00. I'm java.util.Date to initialize the endTime.

Any solutions?

Edit:

This method returns the Current Time:

```
public static Date getCurrentTime() {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        return new Time(hour, minute, second);
    }
```

This is the initialization of endTime:

```
Date endTime = new Date();
```

Comment: Please add more code. Like how have you initialised your `endTime` and `currentTime` variables.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Hi @SyedAhmedJamil, I've edited the post, check it out.

Comment: What are you expecting in both of your variables. I am assuming you are calling `Date endTime = new Date();` at some later time right ? What are you trying to achieve ? I still can't understand what issue you are facing

Comment: The issue is that the date is initialized at 31-12-1969 and later i'm adding it to another date using getTime() metthod. The problem i'm facing is that there is always a 1 day difference between result and expected result.

Comment: For example, if the dates i'm trying to add are: 31-12-1969 07:00:00 and 26-01-2020 00:00:00 then the result will be 25-01-2020 07:00:00 when it must be: 26-01-2020 07:00:00

Comment: Well if its always 1 day difference just add 1 day yourself manually. I know this doesn't sounds like a valid solution. In your question you said " `endTime` is taking 31-12-1969 07:00:00". The way you initialised your `endTime` it will have some current date of 2020. How `endTime` will ever have 31-12-1969 ? Unless you put it yourself. That is what confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timezone can become negative. Try sth. like (pseudocode):

time = time<"01-01-1970 00:00:00" ? "01-01-1970 00:00:00" : time;

But then you compare to UTC instead of timezone. Hope this helps you.